# TRANSACTIONS V2 in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am not getting response in dialog-flow V2 api.ai for transactions?

I have tried with the sample provided by google in [the samples](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-transactions-nodejs).

But it works if i use V1 only. When i change it to V2 i do not get the response.

Can anyone please share a sample code for TRANSACTION in dialog-flow using V2 API.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the bug causing this issue has been fixed. Try re-running the sample.